# If-then constraints in integer linear programming

Tags: if-statement, integer-programming, simplex, mixed-integer-programming

I have a 30*40 matrix. Lets say the components in the matrix are specified with "P" and the related number of the row and column of each "P" is specified by "X" and "Y" accordingly. I have a model that the output should give us the P, X and Y. How can I define constraints (for solving a simplex) which connect P with it's exact X and Y?
I want to say for example:

if X=1 and Y=1 then 
P= 0.1

if X=1 and Y=2 then 
P= 0.5

if X=1 and Y=3 then 
P= 0.8
and so on.

I dont want the model to return a P that does not match it's location in the matrix. How can I achieve this?
[This is the objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5TjQ.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code??

Comment: That just sounds like a 2D array of data. What are your decision variables? What solver are you using? What language?

Comment: I have to use Matlab. So far my model since the model is a nonlinear one, I have to use INLP. First I have to define the model correctly then I have to think about coding.